# How do I count Json data in PHP and get the answer in numbers

Tags: php, json, api, for-loop, foreach

I have some trouble with making a loop that counts all the items in my API (json code). I have tried multiple loops that would count the items. But for you to understand what I am talking about I will first show you what I get with my API response.

```
{ "data": {
"boards": [
  {
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "new_groupxxxx",
        "title": "x"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "x",
        "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "state": "active"
      }
```

This is what I get when I echo my code, I get a lot more items of course but I show you one for an example. I am trying to make a loop that counts all the "items" and brings them back to me with a total number that I then can put in my html table. See the  thins I tried below.

```
$data = count($data); for($i = 0; $i < $data; $i++) {
if $i == $data 
{
    echo json_decode($responseContent);
    console.log($query);
}
```

}

```
$data = count($data) $i = 0; foreach ($data["items"] as $value) {
if($value["id"] != $i){
    $i < $value; $i++;
    echo json_encode($responseContent);
    console.log($query);
}
```

}

Comment: There is no `console.log($query);` in PHP. `$i < $value; $i++;` - should it be `if ($i < $value) $i++;`? Anyway, you should loop `$data['data']['boards']` and do `$total += count($board['items'])`

Comment: I don't understand where I need to put the $total += count($board['items']) . Can you tell me where in my code I need too put this? And what about $data = count($data) and $i = 0. Do I need to edit those or are they good?

Answer (score 0):

Your "items" are inside object which is an element of "boards" array. If you need to count all the items then you may need to loop through "boards" array.

### Example

```
<?php 
 $data=json_decode(YOUR_API_RESPONSE) 

$itemCount=0;

foreach($data->data->boards as $board) {
    $itemCount+=count($board->items);
}
echo "Total number of items =".$itemCount;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have looked into this code and when I execute it with what I got it returns to 0. Is this maybe because I is already defined as 0 or maybe because it doesn't add anything like ++1?